# Would you give me some advice on Elliott's equation?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to solve below equation on mathematica for plotting, but I'm a complete beginner.

```
Y=#A/x*(Sum[((2*0.025)/i^3)*Sech[(x - (1.65 - 25/i^2))/0.031], {i, 1, 5}]+ Integrate[Sech[(x - E)/0.031]/((1 - E^(-2*Pi*Sqrt[0.025/(-1.65 + E)]))*(1 - 1.4*(-1.65 + E))), {E, 1.65, Infinity}])
```

Input:

```
Sum[((2*0.025)/i^3)*Sech[(x - (1.65 - 25/i^2))/0.031], {i, 1, 5}]
```

Output:

```
0.0004 Sech[32.2581 (-0.65 + x)] +  0.00078125 Sech[32.2581 (-0.0875 + x)] +  0.00185185 Sech[32.2581 (1.12778 + x)] +  0.00625 Sech[32.2581 (4.6 + x)] + 0.05 Sech[32.2581 (23.35 + x)]
```

Input:

```
Integrate[Sech[(x - E)/0.031]/((1 - E^(-2*Pi*Sqrt[0.025/(-1.65 + E)]))*(1 - 1.4*(-1.65 + E))), {E, 1.65, Infinity}]
```

> Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in
>   {E,1.65,[Infinity]}. >>

Output:

```
Integrate[-3.26734 Sech[32.2581 (-E + x), {E, 1.65, Infinity}]
```

Please give me some advice.

Comment: You can't use `E` as the integration variable, since in Mathematica `E` is exp function. ?E try different lower case symbol.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I plot the above equation?

Comment: **Help us to help you**, start by showing due diligence: 1, fixing the problem with your variables; 2, reading the documentation for `Plot`; 3, taking the [tour]. Do your best to write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) that may help not only yourself but also future visitors. On a side note, Why not choosing a meaningful name?